# how to implement a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

im trying to create a tic-tac-toe game; but im having a little bit of trouble. 
I have created a list with numbers in it, so when that number is chosen it changes to an x or o. however when my board prints it has the numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 in them and I don't want them to be like that.
my question would be how can I change the characters in an empty list ? would I use indexes or is there another way of doing it

```
board = [0,1,2,
         3,4,5,
         6,7,8]

def gameBoard():
    print("    " "a" "   " "b" "   " "c")
    print("  ""-------------")
    print(("1"),("|"),board[0],"|",board[1], "|" ,board[2], "|")
    print("  ""-------------")
    print(("2"),("|"),board[3],"|",board[4], "|" ,board[5], "|")
    print("  ""-------------")   
    print(("3"),("|"),board[6],"|",board[7], "|" ,board[8], "|")
    print("  ""-------------")    


while True:
    user_input = input("Enter your move: ")
    if user_input == "a1":
        user_input = "0"
    elif user_input == "a2":
        user_input = "3" 
    elif user_input == "a3":
        user_input="6"
    elif user_input == "b1":
        user_input = "1"
    elif user_input == "b2":
        user_input = "4"
    elif user_input== "b3":
        user_input = "7"
    elif user_input == "c1":
        user_input = "2"
    elif user_input == "c2":
        user_input = "5"
    elif user_input == "c3":
        user_input = "8"
    else:
        print("invalid coordinates")
    user_input= int(user_input)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, you are filling the board with ints 0 - 8.  If you check board[7] it will return 7.

I think you want to intialize the board with spaces, so that board[7] will return ' ' (blank space).

You can do board = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

Or more cleanly,

board = [' '] * 9

Hope this helps :)
Using a matrix is also not a bad idea for implementation, but is different than this problem you are trying to solve

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that what you want is a board with strings, not numbers, filled initially with strings of a single space. You can use a single list for this board or a two dimensional array

single list implementation

```
board = [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]
```

example from console:

```
>>> board = [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]
>>> board[2] = "X"
>>> board
[' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
>>> board[0]
' '
>>> board[2]
'X'
>>>
```

2-d array implementation

```
board = [[" "," "," "],[" "," "," "],[" "," "," "]]
```

example from console:

```
>>> board = [[" "," "," "],[" "," "," "],[" "," "," "]]
>>> board[1][2] = "O"
>>> board
[[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', 'O'], [' ', ' ', ' ']]
>>> board[0][1]
' '
>>> board[1][2]
'O'
```

example printing 2D list:

```
>>> board = [["X"," ","X"],[" ","X"," "],["X"," ","X"]]
>>> for row in board:
    string = ""
    for element in row:
        string = string + element
    print(string)


X X
 X 
X X
```

Comment: that's the way I want it . but its also suppose to print out In an actual tic-tac toe board. how do I do that ? cause they way its like that, it prints out in a straight line

Answer (score 0):

Use a two dimensional list!

```
board = [[0,0,0],
         [0,0,0],
         [0,0,0]]
```

And then just use the values you want etc. Then the reference is just:

```
board[row][column]
```

Edit: I kind of misread the question, instead of being 0 through 9, you could make them all empty strings i.e.

```
board[i] = ''
```

or use a dictionary to map numbers to strings

```
board[5] = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary:

```
board = {0:'X', 1:'O', 2:' ',
         3:'X', 4:'O', 5:' ',
         6:'X', 7:'O', 8:' ',
        }

print board[1] # will print O
board[1] = 'X'
print board[1] # will print X
```

Answer (score 0):

You're question isn't entirely complete because you aren't updating the gameboard on each iteration.  However, here are some suggestions:

1. Set your initial board to be full of zeros (or 'O')
2. If you are using a list, all your statements like `user_input = '1'` etc can simply be set to `use_input = 1` to avoid the explicit call to `int`.
3. You change the values of list by simply saying `board[user_input] = 'X'` or `board[user_input] = 'O'`, depending on the player.